# p:fileUpload invalid size message is not localized according locale config

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces, localization

When a user uploads files which is larger than the allowed size he gets a error-message in english and not the language which I set in faces-config.xml

There are any special settings needed to display the error-message in the right language? The other error messages for example on the field I set to required="true" are correct. Also my own messages which I set in Messages_de.properties are working.

Error Message

```
    Invalid file sizeDSC_6773.JPG 2.9 MB
```

faces-config.xml:

```
<locale-config>
  <default-locale>de</default-locale>
  <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
</locale-config>
<message-bundle>
   jsfmessages.Messages_de
</message-bundle>
```

Messages_de.properties:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=bitte ausf\u00fcllen
```

page.xhtml:

```
<p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{eintrag.handleFileUpload}"
    mode="advanced" update="msgFileUpload" auto="true"
    sizeLimit="#{config.fileUploadMaxSize}"
    allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpeg|jpg|png)$/" label="Auswählen"
    disable="false" id="fileUpload" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `fileUpload` tag you can add message (in your language) about invalid file size  in `invalidSizeMessage` attribute.